# How to update MongoDB quickly?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

There is a MongoDB collection A, and another file is text file, now I want to use mapreduce to read the text file and test whether each record exist in A, if it does, the update the record in A according to the corresponding record from text file, or insert the record to A. Now I use the MongoUpdateWritable class to do this thing, but it is too slow, can someone tell me how to improve the speed to do this thing?

The code sample is as fllows:

```
    query.append("x", x);

    update.append("$set", appendObj.append("y", y));

    muw.setQuery(record);
    muw.setModifiers(update);

    context.write(NullWritable.get(), muw);

    job3.setMapOutputValueClass(MongoUpdateWritable.class);
    job3.setOutputFormatClass(MongoOutputFormat.class);
```